# Android Java - Trouble Reading or Writing items from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, file-writing

Here I have attached my code, I'm not able to save any items I add to my to do list. They persist when I add them and do not leave however, when I leave and return they are not staying. Could anyone have a look to see why? Thanks.

TL;DR

1 - They will add to the list
2 - They will be removed from the list once I hold on the item
3 - They will not stay once I exit Activity and return (MAIN PROBLEM!)

```
/**
 * Method to read items from todo text file to the ArrayList
 */

private void readItems() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir(); // file directory set to local file directory
    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt"); // file is set to the file directory + todo.txt

    try {
        items = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile)); // deprecated not sure what to replace this with?
        // if any errors are caught, print stack trace
    } catch (IOException e) {
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}


/**
 * Method to write items from ArrayList to the todo text file
 */

private void writeItems() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir(); // file directory set to the local file directory
    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt"); // file is set to the file directory + todo.txt
    try {
        FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, items); // write to todo.txt with the items added to the array list.
        // if any errors are caught, print stack trace
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //output error if caught
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be because you make a new arrayList in your oncreate method...so the list is cleared every time you restart the app

Comment: I'll try to fix it! Thanks

Comment: You've fixed it. Thanks very much